# Is there any way to filter files by their content in FTP? (not by file names)

Tags: ftp, vsftpd

I'm trying to filter the content of an FTP directory to see if any of the files contain a certain phrase that I want to look for.

I've been trying to find for a few hours if there's any way to do this, but with no luck at all!

How can I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot filter the files on FTP server by their contents without actually transferring the contents to the local machine (aka downloading the files).

So download the files and use any convenient local tool to find the files you need.

---

Though you might have a different way to access the server that may allow remote-side filtering. Such as a *shell access*.